# How can I get the ImageIcon displayed in a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

```
public ImageIcon getIcon(){
   return button.getIcon();
}

public void moveTo(Square j){
   JButton current = new JButton();
   current = button;
   button.setIcon(j.getIcon());
   button.setIcon(current.getIcon());
}
```

Here's the problem. Button is just a simple `JButton` without content, and with conditions I'm adding different content into Button. Though when I created the move method, which will switch the two images of two buttons, I failed to attempt to get the `ImageIcon` of the `JButton`. It reports this error in the first method:

```
Icon cannot be converted to ImageIcon
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) In this case the code should probably hold a reference to a model that describes the state of the GUI, references to the `Image` instances to display on various conditions, and a method to refresh the GUI with the images as indicated by the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon is an interface which is implemented by the class ImageIcon so inherently every ImageIcon is an Icon so you can cast the Icon to imageIcon as follows

```
public ImageIcon getIcon(){
  return (ImageIcon)button.getIcon(); 
 /*getIcon() returns Icon and  ImageIcon is child 
 of Icon so you can cast as you cast parent class reference to child class in this 
 case it is interface acting as parent*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it through the constructor:

```
JButton button = new JButton("text", icon);
```

The better way is to create an action and create the button from the action.  Then you can update the icon of the action and it will be udpated everywhere that action is used: the button, menu bars, popup menus, etc.

```
Action action = new AbstractAction("text", icon) {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
//place the action in an ActionMap 
Jbutton button = new JButton(action);
```

Then when you need to update the icon it would just be

```
getActionMap().get(key).putValue(Action.LARGE_ICON_KEY, icon); //for buttons
getActionMap().get(key).putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON_KEY, icon); //for menus
```